# Copy result to another layout's editText object (Android Studio)

Tags: android, qr-code

I'd like to read the QR code on ***activity_reader.xml***  (when I click the button it reads the qr code), and after I want to copy this text to the ***activity_main.xml*** 's EditText object called ***mainText***. And go back to the activity_main.
The app stop working.

This is how main Activity look like:
[image]

The layout where I read QR code:
[image]

**ReaderActivity.java:**

```
package com.example.newpc.qrcode;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentResult;

public class ReaderActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button scan_btn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_reader);
        scan_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scan_btn);
        final Activity activity = this;
        scan_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
                integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);
                integrator.setPrompt("Scan");
                integrator.setCameraId(0);
                integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
                integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
                integrator.initiateScan();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(result != null){
            if(result.getContents()==null){
                Toast.makeText(this, "You cancelled the scanning", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(this, result.getContents(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mainText);
                editText.setText(result.getContents());

            }
        }
        else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 2 things: here in your code I don't see any reference to activity_main. Second thing, please check what is the exact error in your logcat and share it.

Comment: share your logcat error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make an **Intent** from **ReaderActivity** to **MainActivity** and putExtra String value

Put this in **onActivityResult** when **result.getContents() != null**

```
String qrStr = result.getContents();
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("qrStr", qrStr);
startActivity(intent);
```

MainActivity in **onCreate** function

```
Intent intent = getIntent;
String qrStr = (String) intent.getExtras().getString("qrStr");
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mainText);
editText.setText(qrStr);
```

I hope I understand your question well and helped.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get the string which one you want to copy. It might be from edit text for Text-view or any-other results (Can be from scanned link) or whatever.

```
String copyLink = yourField.getText(); //

ClipboardManager clipboardManager = (ClipboardManager)
getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
ClipData clipData = ClipData.newPlainText("Data", copyLink);
assert clipboardManager != null;
clipboardManager.setPrimaryClip(clipData);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Link copied", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

if you use button to copy the text, so use this code inside onClick method;

Hope it helps you

Happy Coding